# Apache can't get viewed from outside of my LAN

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, router, nat

## I fixed it in PORTS TRIGGER menu of my router. Thanks you anyway

I have a weird problem related with (*i think*) my cable-router and my configured vhosts in Apache2.

The point is I can't access from outside of my LAN to any of my configured vhosts if I set the http port of Apache to 80 and i add a NAT rule for it. Otherwise, if I set my Apache port to 81 (or any else) with its respective NAT rule on my router it works.

My router is an ARRIS TG952S and I am using Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

**ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

**vhost1.mydomain.net.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName vhost1.mydomain.net
    ServerAlias vhost1.mydomain.net www.vhost1.mydomain.net
```

**vhost2.mydomain.net.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName vhost2.mydomain.net
    ServerAlias vhost2.mydomain.net www.vhost2.mydomain.net
```

**DNS records (using [FreeDNS](http://freedns.afraid.org/)) are:**

```
mydomain.net        --> pointing to another server
vhost1.mydomain.net --> pointing to my server
vhost2.mydomain.net --> pointing to my server
```

**iptables -L -n**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-apache-noscript  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
fail2ban-apache  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-apache-noscript (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Thanks you

Comment: What do you get when try to access your website on port 80?

Comment: Just get timeout

Comment: I edited again with the configuration of vhosts files

Comment: When you do

wget http://server.external.ip

what happens?

Comment: Connecting with server.external.ip:80... failed: Connection timeout.
Retrying.

Comment: Does your router have a web interface??  If so, does it run on port 80, and do you have remote management turned on?

Comment: Yes, it have. But there is not an option to enable/disable remote management. Anyway, you can't access to the router's webinterface from outside of my LAN. So I think that it is already disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ISP is probably blocking the port. Are you on a consumer grade line? What ISP?

Comment: I think that it is not an ISP block. In my opinion, it could be anything related to ServerName directive or something like that. I mean, an error in my vhosts & apache configuration files. Anyway, my ISP is Telecable (Spain)

Comment: I forget to mention it but a month ago it works great. I think that it get broken when I changed that mydomain.net does not point to my server. I mean, just the subdomains vhost1.mydomain.net and vhost2.mydomain.net pointing to my server, but no mydomain.net

Comment: @JavierMartinez Check the forwarding rule in the router, I think you must forward to a new server now.

Comment: @ott-- the rule is OK

Comment: @ott-- I think that the problem is related to ServerName directive. What do I must have there? ServerName public_ip?

Comment: @JavierMartinez You said that the vhosts run on a different server now. The change must be made in the router, not in the apache config.

Comment: @ott-- No, I think that i didn't explained so well. I mean that BEFORE my domain.net points to my IP SERVER and i used it in ServerName directive also

Comment: So, is your "domain.net" DNS entry pointing to your IP from the ISP? Or the server's internal address? You may want to verify that your ISP hasn't changed your external IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out firewall issues, please check if you've iptables configured and blocking port 80

```
$ iptables -L -n
```

Perhaps, it is even worth looking in /etc/hosts.deny
Otherwide, you should contact your ISP about it as they may be blocking the port to block any commercial use of the internet connection.

Comment: I edited the question with the output of iptables -L -n. /etc/hosts.deny is clean

Answer (score 0):

Use tcpdump to see if the packets arrive at your server.  Disable your firewall then run tcpdump as follows:

tcpdump -i eth0 dst port 80

Open a browser from an external computer and surf to your server.  If your server receives packets then something else is wrong.  Check if apache is running then check that all your apache config files are ok.